# Настройка роутинга PHP - не работают запросы с кириллицей

Tags: php

не работает скрипт с кириллицей (страница не найдена)

правило из класса Router

```
 $route = preg_replace('/{([0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ]+):([^\}]+)}/u', '(?P<\1>\2)', $route);
```

правило из массива routes.php

```
'main/{search:\?search=[0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ+]+}' => [
        'controller' => 'main',
        'action' => 'index',
    ],
```

http://localhost/fw/main/?search=some+text - так работает

[http://localhost/fw/main/?search=чтото](http://localhost/fw/main/?search=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE)    - так не работает (грузит 404 страница не найдена)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php
php_value default_charset utf-8
```

htaccess

Comment: а вы не хотите воспользоваться parse_url  и parse_str ?

Comment: splash58, это надо будет менять всю логику и структуру сайта?

Comment: route class только. Чтоб не регулярками парсить урл

Comment: splash58, нужно только get параметр кириллические буквы добавить, разве из исходящих данных это не получится сделать?

Comment: echo  поставьте перед preg_replace. Давайте глянем, что вы получаете

Comment: splash58, main/index/(?P\d+)main/delete/(?P\d+)main/(?P\?search=[0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ+]+)main/addmain/postsaboutcontactpost/(?P\d+)admin/loginadmin/logoutadmin/addadmin/edit/(?P\d+)admin/edit_staus/(?P\d+)admin/delete/(?P\d+)admin/posts/(?P\d+)admin/posts

Comment: Я хотел посмотретьь на $route в preg_replace. И добавляйте все в вопрос

Comment: splash58 это оно и есть

Comment: `main/index/(?P\d+)main/delete/(?P\d+)main/(?P\?search=[0-9a-zA-Zа-яёА-ЯЁ+]+)` из этого вы хотите вынуть `чтото` ?

Comment: splash58, хочу попадая на параметр ?search=текст , что бы оно работало, с латиницей все прекрасно работает

Comment: Я извиняюсь, я не могу вам помочь, не понимаю сути

Comment: splash58, http://localhost/fw/main/?search=some+text  так работает, http://localhost/fw/main/?search=чтото так не работает(страница не найдена), вот и вся суть

Comment: какая строка в коде вызывает 404 ошибку, каковы входные данные, что не срабатывает? Иначе, это гадания

Comment: splash58, тот же класс Router вызывает  if (class_exists($path)) {...} else {  View::errorCode(404);}, входные данные на GET параметр кириллицей не работает, латиницей работает